# Intellij doesn't recognize JDK Home

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I've looked all over, and can't seem to find anything on Intellij not recognizing JDKs.

I just installed Ubuntu Mate 18 stable version. Should I try a different distro or reinstall? I've already tried reinstalling Intellij.

Here's what I'm getting. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yudos.png

Comment: Maybe you can try to use oracle's jdk. If it works, then probably your open jdk got some issues.

Comment: what is the intellij version

Comment: @Keaz It's the newest one.

Comment: Tried selecting /bin folder?

Comment: @LukeSpringWalker already tried

Comment: @weaver No luck. Same error.

Comment: java -version works?

Comment: @weaver yup, Java itself is fine.

Comment: Maybe try a different version of IntelliJ?

Comment: It works fine with OpenJDK on Ubuntu 18.04. The only difference for what you mentioned is that I use KDE, but this should not be the issue. Try checking your JDK settings. I was really confused one because I  brought projects from other computer, and they were using project specific configuration, instead of the application global jdk.

Comment: @Victor I feel like my Ubuntu is just acting weird. Some features don't really work.

Comment: well, if you notice more issues maybe you can go for a complete reinstall. just know, for the purpose of this question, that it does work, pretty smoothly actually. initially I was having issues with wayland, but I was trying wayland just for a feature I like. now I am back to X + KDE, no issues so far.

Comment: @mgershen Same result.

Comment: @Victor That's my plan. I'm going back to ol' reliable Mint.

Comment: Can you add the output of `uname -a` to your question - just so we get more information about your OS.

Comment: @JohnFarrelly I couldn't wait around to troubleshoot. Installed Mint, and it's working as intended.